# psycopg2 is not handling "timezone('America/Chicago',now())" properly

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
def fetch_last_recorded_activity_date(l_pgsql_pool, l_pg_conn, l_sql_statement):
    """

    :param l_pgsql_pool: Postgres Connection Pool
    :param l_pg_conn: Postgres connection object to run various operations
    :return:
    """
    try:
        with l_pg_conn.cursor() as cur:  # If connectionPool is being used whilte creating new connection,it
            # tries to use existing connection as much as possible. With in connection, you can have multiple cursors
            # for various operations
            cur.execute(l_sql_statement)
            last_recorded_activity_details = cur.fetchone()
            return last_recorded_activity_details

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        log.error(error)
    finally:
        if cur is not None:
            cur.close()


    while True:
            doc = {}
            sql_statement = """
                             select max(completed_date) at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'america/Chicago' as LastRecordedDate, timezone('america/Chicago',now()) as TimeofCheck
                             from adw.activity_fact
                             where completed_date at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'america/Chicago' between current_date and current_date+1               
                             """
            last_recorded_activity_date, current_date_frm_server = fetch_last_recorded_activity_date(
                pgsql_pool, pg_conn,sql_statement)
            log.debug(
                'Last recorded activity date: {} Servertime when pgsql'
                ' to fetch last recorded activity date is executed: {}'
                    .format(last_recorded_activity_date, current_date_frm_server)
            )
            time.sleep(20)
            sql_statement=''
            current_date_frm_server = None
```

I am trying to fetch query execution time from the server. To do so, I am using `timezone('America/Chicago', now())` as `TimeofCheck` within SQL statement.

I am submitting a query to Postgres every 20 seconds.  Please find the relevant code above. Somehow, psycopg2 is caching
the result of TimeofCheck and it's not updating at all. The above script is generating the below results.

> 01-27 16:40:57 [DEBUG:MainProcess] Last recorded activity date: 2020-01-27 16:39:53.028000 Servertime when pgsql to fetch last recorded activity date is executed: 2020-01-27 16:41:05.033359
>
> 01-27 16:41:18 [DEBUG:MainProcess] Last recorded activity date: 2020-01-27 16:39:55.385000 Servertime when pgsql to fetch last recorded activity date is executed: 2020-01-27 16:41:05.033359
>
> 01-27 16:41:38 [DEBUG:MainProcess] Last recorded activity date: 2020-01-27 16:40:42.074000 Servertime when pgsql to fetch last recorded activity date is executed: 2020-01-27 16:41:05.033359
>
> 01-27 16:41:59 [DEBUG:MainProcess] Last recorded activity date: 2020-01-27 16:40:50.706000 Servertime when pgsql to fetch last recorded activity date is executed: 2020-01-27 16:41:05.033359
>
> 01-27 16:42:19 [DEBUG:MainProcess] Last recorded activity date: 2020-01-27 16:41:30.628000 Servertime when pgsql to fetch last recorded activity date is executed: 2020-01-27 16:41:05.033359
>
> 01-27 16:42:39 [DEBUG:MainProcess] Last recorded activity date: 2020-01-27 16:41:30.628000 Servertime when pgsql to fetch last recorded activity date is executed: 2020-01-27 16:41:05.033359

It's getting `LastRecordedDate` correctly but somehow `TimeOfCheck` is returning the constant value.

Environment Information

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(psycopg2.__version__)
2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
```

Answer (score 2):

now() is the timestamp at the start of the transaction and all of your queries are running in the same transaction.  Therefore, they all share the same timestamp.  You should either use autocommit mode or commit the transaction between each statement.  It's not good practice to hold the transaction open any longer than it has to be, so you should be closing it before sleeping.

Comment: Totally agree with @Jeremy but If you have to do it this way you can use STATEMENT_TIMESTAMP() instead of NOW(). If you continue with this, some day you will cause DBAs to have headaches...

Comment: Yup. Enabling auto-commit fixed issue.  I wasn't aware by default every operation gets run as transactions.